# KS-test between each columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov

I was wondering if there is a package or a new way that can perform KS-test between each columns of a matrix more quickly than use 2 loops? Thanks!

```
all <- c()
for (i in (1:(ncol(a)-1))){
  for (j in ((i+1):ncol(a))){
    res <- ks.test(i,j)
    all <- rbind(all,res)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a 5 column matrix, each containing 10 draws from a different normal distribution:

```r
set.seed(1)

a <- sapply(seq(1, 3, 0.5), function(x) rnorm(10, x))

a
#>            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#>  [1,] 0.3735462  3.0117812 2.9189774 3.858680 2.835476
#>  [2,] 1.1836433  1.8898432 2.7821363 2.397212 2.746638
#>  [3,] 0.1643714  0.8787594 2.0745650 2.887672 3.696963
#>  [4,] 2.5952808 -0.7146999 0.0106483 2.446195 3.556663
#>  [5,] 1.3295078  2.6249309 2.6198257 1.122940 2.311244
#>  [6,] 0.1795316  1.4550664 1.9438713 2.085005 2.292505
#>  [7,] 1.4874291  1.4838097 1.8442045 2.105710 3.364582
#>  [8,] 1.7383247  2.4438362 0.5292476 2.440687 3.768533
#>  [9,] 1.5757814  2.3212212 1.5218499 3.600025 2.887654
#> [10,] 0.6946116  2.0939013 2.4179416 3.263176 3.881108
```

We can get all unique combinations of 2 columns using `combn` and apply `ks.test` to these pairs of columns, retreiving all the p values in a single vector like this:

```r
p <- apply(combn(ncol(a), 2), 2, function(x) ks.test(a[,x[1]], a[, x[2]])$p.val)

p
#>  [1] 0.1678213427 0.0524475524 0.0020567668 0.0002165018 0.9944575548
#>  [6] 0.4175236528 0.0123406006 0.1678213427 0.0524475524 0.4175236528
```

To make it clearer which comparison these p values refer to, we can store the results in a 5 x 5 matrix that will be the same as the result of your loop. Note though, that we have only had to run `ks.test` 10 times instead of 25 because the diagonal is already known to be p = 1, and the matrix is symmetrical:

```
m <- matrix(0, ncol(a), ncol(a))

m[lower.tri(m)] <- round(p, 3)
m <- t(m)
m[lower.tri(m)] <- round(p, 3)
diag(m) <- 1

m
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,] 1.000 0.168 0.052 0.002 0.000
#> [2,] 0.168 1.000 0.994 0.418 0.012
#> [3,] 0.052 0.994 1.000 0.168 0.052
#> [4,] 0.002 0.418 0.168 1.000 0.418
#> [5,] 0.000 0.012 0.052 0.418 1.000
```

Alternatively, you could give `p` the names of the columns compared:

```r
names(p) <- apply(combn(ncol(a), 2), 2, paste, collapse = "-")

p
#>          1-2          1-3          1-4          1-5          2-3 
#> 0.1678213427 0.0524475524 0.0020567668 0.0002165018 0.9944575548 
#>          2-4          2-5          3-4          3-5          4-5 
#> 0.4175236528 0.0123406006 0.1678213427 0.0524475524 0.4175236528
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a really good iead that can save me half the time!But as for a lagre matrix (like 1000 columns), it's also time-consuming. I was wondering if there is a good way to speed up?